# Stack Overflow exception at Database.EnsureCreated EF 7 ASP.NET 5 MVC 6

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I am encountering an error at Database creation at Application Start whereas the exact same code works perfectly fine in all other projects.

**Startup function in Startup.cs**

```
public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    // Set up configuration sources.
    var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
            .AddEnvironmentVariables();

    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        // This will push telemetry data through Application Insights pipeline faster, allowing you to view results immediately.
            builder.AddApplicationInsightsSettings(developerMode: true);
    }
    Configuration = builder.Build();
    Globals.Configuration = Configuration;
    Globals.HostingEnvironment = env;
    Globals.EnsureDatabaseCreated();
}
```

**Globals.EnsureDatabaseCreated()**

```
public static void EnsureDatabaseCreated()
    {
        var optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder();
        if (HostingEnvironment.IsDevelopment()) optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(Configuration["Data:dev:DataContext"]);
        else if (HostingEnvironment.IsStaging()) optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(Configuration["Data:staging:DataContext"]);
        else if (HostingEnvironment.IsProduction()) optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(Configuration["Data:live:DataContext"]);
        var context = new ApplicationContext(optionsBuilder.Options);
        context.Database.EnsureCreated();

        optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder();
        if (HostingEnvironment.IsDevelopment()) optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(Configuration["Data:dev:TransientContext"]);
        else if (HostingEnvironment.IsStaging()) optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(Configuration["Data:staging:TransientContext"]);
        else if (HostingEnvironment.IsProduction()) optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(Configuration["Data:live:TransientContext"]);
        new TransientContext(optionsBuilder.Options).Database.EnsureCreated();
    }
```

**ApplicationContext.cs**

```
public class ApplicationContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Models.Security.User> Logins { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Models.Security.Session> Sessions { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Models.Security.Verification> VerificationTokens { get; set; }

    public DbSet<Models.CRM.User> Users { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Models.CRM.Organization> Merchants { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Models.CRM.LinkedAddress> Shops { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Models.CRM.ContactDetail> ContactDetails { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Models.CRM.Location> Locations { get; set; }

    public ApplicationContext(DbContextOptions options) : base(options)
    {
    }
}
```

Error Screenshot

[image]

Comment: Could have been a bug, such as https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/3799. Also, http://stackoverflow.com/help/no-one-answers. Starting a bounty on a question is a good way to draw more attention and get answers.

Answer (score 0):

After waiting for two days for an answer, unfortunately i ended up creating a new project and copying code there and it worked. Seems like a configuration issue.

Note: Since i didn't received any answers i am marking this as the correct answer. If a user comes in future and share their viewpoints, i will be happy to mark their answer if it adds some value to future readers.

Comment: @Rabadash8820 I didn't marked it as it's not a solution, and i never came back to this question.