# EF Core migration fails, table already created

Tags: c#, ef-core-2.1

Here is my DbContext class

```
public class BlogContext : DbContext
{
    public BlogContext (DbContextOptions<BlogContext> options)
        : base(options)
    { }
    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Post> Posts { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Comment> Comments  { get; set; }
}
```

And here are the commands i enter into the nugget console untill the error comes up

> PM> add-migration AddNotNull
>   The EF Core tools version '2.1.1-rtm-30846' is older than that of the runtime '2.1.3-rtm-32065'. Update the tools for the latest features and bug fixes.
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure[10403]
>         Entity Framework Core 2.1.3-rtm-32065 initialized 'BlogContext' using provider 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer' with options: None
>   To undo this action, use Remove-Migration.
>   PM> update-database
>   The EF Core tools version '2.1.1-rtm-30846' is older than that of the runtime '2.1.3-rtm-32065'. Update the tools for the latest features and bug fixes.
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure[10403]
>         Entity Framework Core 2.1.3-rtm-32065 initialized 'BlogContext' using provider 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer' with options: None
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20101]
>         Executed DbCommand (11ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
>         SELECT OBJECT_ID(N'[__EFMigrationsHistory]');
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20101]
>         Executed DbCommand (3ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
>         SELECT OBJECT_ID(N'[__EFMigrationsHistory]');
>   Applying migration '20181113132251_AddNotNull'.
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20101]
>         Executed DbCommand (7ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
>         SELECT [MigrationId], [ProductVersion]
>         FROM [__EFMigrationsHistory]
>         ORDER BY [MigrationId];
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations[20402]
>         Applying migration '20181113132251_AddNotNull'.
>   Failed executing DbCommand (5ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']

```
CREATE TABLE [Users] (
[IDUser] int NOT NULL IDENTITY,
[Username] nvarchar(max) NOT NULL,
[Password] nvarchar(max) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_Users] PRIMARY KEY ([IDUser]));
```

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): There is already an object named 'Users' in the database.
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteNonQueryTds(String methodName, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Boolean asyncWrite)
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Boolean sendToPipe, Int32 timeout, Boolean asyncWrite, String methodName)
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.RelationalCommand.Execute(IRelationalConnection connection, DbCommandMethod executeMethod, IReadOnlyDictionary`2 parameterValues)
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.RelationalCommand.ExecuteNonQuery(IRelationalConnection connection, IReadOnlyDictionary`2 parameterValues)
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.MigrationCommand.ExecuteNonQuery(IRelationalConnection connection, IReadOnlyDictionary`2 parameterValues)
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.MigrationCommandExecutor.ExecuteNonQuery(IEnumerable`1 migrationCommands, IRelationalConnection connection)
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.Migrator.Migrate(String targetMigration)
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.MigrationsOperations.UpdateDatabase(String targetMigration, String contextType)
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.UpdateDatabase.<>c__DisplayClass0_1.<.ctor>b__0()
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.Execute(Action action)
>   ClientConnectionId:123d7ce8-1ece-4ad9-aa48-bd44c7179be1
>   Error Number:2714,State:6,Class:16
>   There is already an object named 'Users' in the database.

All i did was add [Required()] to most of my fields.
And sorry for the formatting. SO thinks that the create table is a code block in this quote..

EDIT: The asnwer to the problem is that Database.EnsureCreated() method creates the database without any migration, any disables (denies?) migrations, so that's why i couldn't create any migrations.

Comment: Please try to run `update-database -verbose`. That way you might see additional errors in your console output.
Also: it is strange, that EF wants to re-create your table. Are previous migrations present in your `__MigrationHistory` table?

Comment: @nilsK Can't add the -verbose text, because SO again thinks i have code there, which i can't find in the mess....

Comment: @nilsK For now - https://pastebin.com/DBq9Zcen and there are no previous migrations in the table.

Comment: Okay, not more info in that output ... did you checkd your migration history?
Also, what about that warning `The EF Core tools version '2.1.1-rtm-30846' is older than that of the runtime '2.1.3-rtm-32065'. `? Could you update that package?

Comment: @nilsK No previous migrations. And how can i update it, if my EF Core Tools comes with MVC. (No nugget package)

Comment: When there are no previous migrations, how did you created that table? Manually?
You will need to do (kind of) everything with EF, when using code first concept. `__MigrationHistory` is used by EF to analyze what is already done. When EF does not know that a table is created, it tries to create it. That is the reason of your error message above stating `There is already an object named 'Users' in the database`.

Comment: @nilsK Wierd. I went with code-first approach. Created my table classes, ran a .Database.EnsureCreated() and saw the tables created. So what should i do now? Not use .Database.EnsureCreated() and try to migrate database without it being created first? EDIT: Just checked https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38238043/how-and-where-to-call-database-ensurecreated-and-database-migrate and that command creates tables without migrating.. You can add that as the answer.

Comment: Not entirely sure, but `Database.EnsureCreated` seems to check if the `Database` is created or not. I don't know, if this also checks for existing tables. I did just a short web search, though: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38241900/2590375