# entityframework core create table if table not exists?

Tags: entity-framework-core

we don't use migration because our existing databases are with clients devices and want to create additional tables to their databases after updates for feature extensions...

there was an option like `Context.DbEntity.Create();` in `ef6` but not getting in `ef core` to do so...

I used  the below but it also not creating tables which doesn't exist...

```
try{

  var databaseCreator = (Database.GetService<IDatabaseCreator>() as RelationalDatabaseCreator);

            databaseCreator.CreateTables();

        }

        catch (Exception ex)

        {

            System.Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);

        }
```

Regards-
Sanjeeb

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38238043/how-and-where-to-call-database-ensurecreated-and-database-migrate

Comment: I have tried the link but this approach only works on first launch.

If I want to add other table afterward, it's not working...

the same can be done by ado.net but it's so long and lengthy to write scripts for every table...

Comment: is no one here to help me ?