# Upgrade from .NET 6 to .NET 8: Custom Context with Configuration - DB First

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, .net-6.0, .net-8.0, scaffold

I want to upgrade from .NET 6 to .NET 8. I have to use DB first approach.
In .NET 6 I created a custom context to be able to pass a connectionString from the injected Configuration.

```
public partial class ScaffoldedCustomContext : ScaffoldedContext
{
    private IConfiguration _config;

    public ScaffoldedCustomContext(IConfiguration Configuration)
    {
        _config = Configuration;
    }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        if (!optionsBuilder.IsConfigured)
        {
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(_config.GetValue<string>("connectionString"));
        }
    }
}
```

After "switching" to .NET 8 (package upgrades and changing my VS code launch.json) the DB scaffold creates the following context file:

```
public partial class ScaffoldedContext : DbContext
{
    public ScaffoldedContext(DbContextOptions<ScaffoldedContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }
    ...
}
```

with .net6 I was also given an empty default constructor:

```
public ScaffoldedContext()
{
}
```

In some of my methods for example in "Main" I needed to create a context like this:

```
 var _context = new ScaffoldedCustomContext(Configuration);
```

But with .NET 8 I get the error message that the required parameter options is missing.

How can I deal with that? Do I need to modify `ScaffoldedCustomContext` or do I have to create an options object - if yes, how?

Thank you.

Comment: why don't you just resolve the ScaffoldedContext  from IServiceProvider ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Arguably you don't need `ScaffoldedCustomContext` class at all. `ScaffoldedContext` is generated as [partial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/partial-classes-and-methods) so you should be able to just create a file named something like `ScaffoldedContext.Custom` and place it near the generated one (be sure to place them in the same namespace) and move all custom stuff there:

   ```cs
    public partial class ScaffoldedContext
    {
        private IConfiguration _config;

        public ScaffoldedContext(IConfiguration Configuration)
        {
            _config = Configuration;
        }

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            if (!optionsBuilder.IsConfigured)
            {
                optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(_config.GetValue<string>("connectionString"));
            }
        }
    }
   ```
2. Without seeing your `Main` it is hard to tell what is the best course of action is but

   - Depending on the setup you potentially can just resolve the `ScaffoldedContext` in the `Main` - see for example [Cannot resolve scoped service from root provider in ASP.NET Core 6](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72447401/2501279)
   - Similar to the previous - register [context factory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/dbcontext-configuration/#using-a-dbcontext-factory-eg-for-blazor), resolve and use it to construct the context
   - Construct the options so you don't need the custom constructor:

     ```cs
     var options = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<ScaffoldedContext>()
         .UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetValue<string>("connectionString"))
         .Options;
     var ctx = new ScaffoldedContext(options);
     ```