# Access Registed Scoped Services and Transient Services using GetService()

Tags: asp.net, .net-core, dependency-injection, .net-8.0

Can find the reason why can use Transient Services but Scoped Services

// in programe.cs

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.Services.AddTransient<IConfigurateServices, ConfigurateServices>();
var app = builder.Build();
var test2 = app.Services.GetService<IConfigurateServices>();
```

with this approarch, it work well (Singleton Also), but when i want to change it scoped Services
i get error "Cannot resolve scoped service 'ConfigurationProject.Services.IConfigurateServices' from root".

```
builder.Services.AddScoped<IConfigurateServices, ConfigurateServices>();
```

i also check some issue and got solution but i don't know exacty why?
is Transient Services created when app start ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot resolve scoped service from root provider in ASP.NET Core 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72447401/cannot-resolve-scoped-service-from-root-provider-in-asp-net-core-6)

Answer (score 0):

You need to [create scope](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.serviceproviderserviceextensions.createscope?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0) before calling the Scoped service.

```
public static void DoSomething(WebApplication app)
{
    using IServiceScope? scope = app.Services.CreateScope();
    IConfigurateServices configService = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IConfigurateServices>();
}
```